# Turksh characters in string resources

Tags: android, string, special-characters, android-resources

How to add Turkish special characters in `string.xml`?
And then add them into `Textview` without using a `WebView`?

I have no idea about it.

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand your question - are you having a problem having entered Turkish characters, attempting to setup a translation, or not able to actually type in the characters?

Comment: Unclear what the problem is, doesn't it just work when you add strings to `values-tr/strings.xml`?

Comment: Can't you use the Unicode codes? i.e.: `\u20ba` for `₺`? Or the equivalent HTML entity: `&#8378;`

Comment: @Rotwang, thx,exactly what I need)

Comment: Addaed as an answer, so that you can accept it and remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the Unicode codes, i.e.: `\u20ba` for `₺`
Or the equivalent HTML entity: `&#8378;`, if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Without further context from OP, I'm just going to guess what he means -

try using `CDATA` in your strings.xml. It's an escape block that allows characters and markup.

https://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/CDATASection.html

```
<string name="my_string">
    <![CDATA[            
     Bunlar türk karakterleri örneği
     ]]>
```